# Running a docker command in docker build

Tags: docker, docker-in-docker

I have an application which uses docker to build itself, and I want to build a docker image of it. This requires exposing the `docker.sock` to the application during the `docker build` command (similar to adding a `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` argument to a `docker run` command).

It there any way I can do this or should I resort to building in a virtual machine and copying the build artefacts into a container?
The `Dockerfile` look like this:

```
FROM docker

RUN docker run --rm -v /opt/<myapp>:/opt/<myapp> <myapp> /build_and_install.sh /opt/<myapp>

# etc...
```

Comment: Why don't you run the `docker run` step as a previous step outside of the dockerfile? When I need to do prior setup for a Dockerfile I use a Makefile

Comment: @stacksonstacks this is a Linux web application (surprisingly written in C++) which I want to build on a Mac. I could build on the Mac in a docker and copy the build artifacts to another docker like I said, but I’d like to avoid that. Besides, the build process has many steps (all of which use docker) and I really want an image layer for each step.

Comment: Treat each step as a seperate image. Then you could use `FROM <previous_image>` in subsequent images to keep build cache functionality

Comment: looks like `multi-stage` build is the way to go

Comment: Okay - but why?

Answer (score 0):

Your usecase is a little unclear. That said, in many cases this can be done with a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/). Docker has put out a sample Java application with a [good example of a multi-stage Dockerfile](https://github.com/dockersamples/javaee-demo/blob/master/movieplex7/Dockerfile).