# Multistage Builds with Testcontainers

Tags: docker, maven, testcontainers, docker-buildkit, multistage

I'm trying to use Testcontainers inside the Multistage Build Dockerfile, and it's currently failing with :

```
ERROR   --- [           main] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy       : Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration. Attempted configurations were:
ERROR   --- [           main] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy       :     UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception InvalidConfigurationException (Could not find unix domain socket). Root cause NoSuchFileException (/var/run/docker.sock)
ERROR   --- [           main] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy       : As no valid configuration was found, execution cannot continue
```

Is there a way to mount /var/run/docker.sock in a Multistage build ? Or is there an alternative than having to mount the docker.sock ?

Comment: Docker in docker has serious security problems if this is something you need in a production pipeline .

Comment: It's only for Testcontainers, which we're using for Integration Testing only.

Comment: Why do you need Testcontainers as part of building an image?  Can you just compile the application without running its integration tests at that point?

Comment: @DavidMaze We're building an image that'll be deployed on prod. And so we want to make sure all tests pass before we build. I understand we can separate it in 2 phases where we first run all CI tests with a separate docker run, and then build the image separately. But only if Docker's multistage build can give us a way to mount docker.sock, we wouldn't need to run it 2 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, accessing Docker (and specifically the Docker socket of the host at `/var/run/docker.sock`) is not trivially possible at the current point in time. However, you can configure the Docker build to access the daemon over the network, as outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62549781/1396362) answer.